# React image upload component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking for a React image upload component that provides most/all of the following features:

- Supports upload of multiple images
- Shows a thumbnail/preview of the selected images

On mobile devices it should allow access to the camera, so that a user can either select an image stored on the device, or take a photo of the image to be uploaded.

This component will be used in a React browser app (as opposed to a React native app).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [React Dropzone Uploader](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start), which gives you file previews (including image thumbnails) out of the box, and also handles uploads for you.

```js
import 'react-dropzone-uploader/dist/styles.css'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone-uploader'

const Uploader = () => {  
  return (
    <Dropzone
      getUploadParams={() => ({ url: 'https://httpbin.org/post' })} // specify upload params and url for your files
      onChangeStatus={({ meta, file }, status) => { console.log(status, meta, file) }}
      onSubmit={(files) => { console.log(files.map(f => f.meta)) }}
      accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*"
    />
  )
}
```

Uploads have progress indicators, and they can be cancelled or restarted. The UI is totally customizable.

Full disclosure: I wrote this library to address a lot of the shortcomings and excessive boilerplate required by [React Dropzone](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/why-rdu#react-dropzone).

Answer (score 1):

[React Dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone) is probably your best bet.

It is based off [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and can handle image previews, accessing images from the file system or from the camera, as well as multiple uploads at once.